# Linux Login screen loop - disk space issue

Tags: linux, disk-usage

I'm running a dual boot system on my computer (windows 10 and Linux mint cinnamon) lately I used only the Windows OS, and few days ago i tried to enter the Linux OS and got stuck in a login screen loop.

I read about the issue and figured out using `df -h` that my `"/"` dir is at 100% capacity.

with the help of a friend we mounted the ram and installed `ncdu` to see what's taking that much space.

we figured out the for some reason `timeshift` had around 9GB of snapshots. we deleted those snapshots and then the login screen loop issue was solved. I turned off writing permissions on timeshift directory and it seemed like everything worked well.

The morning later, I logged to the Linux system, and while surfing the web (minor usage) my pc got stuck, I rebooted and login screen loop issue was back. `df -h` shows 100% capacity in `"/"` but now when I run `ncdu /` I can see that the sizes of all files doesn't sum up to the max.

I would be happy if anyone can help me solve this problem and maybe find out what is filling my disk space? yesterday is was at 50% cap and today morning it's 100% again.

Thanks